# How to properly setup my Ionic (Angular) dev machine with self-signed certificate?

Tags: ionic-framework, https, ssl-certificate

I'm working on a Ionic-Angular app and faced quite a few issues due to clear text traffic. So I decided to switch to https even while coding but it wasn't so easy.

I open this question and propose the answer I found to keep a trace and hopefully save you some time if you would like to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

I now have a repo for certificates generation scripts: https://github.com/ch4mpy/self-signed-certificate-generation

### Prerequisite

You need a hostname for your dev machine. This name will be declared in certificates and https services will be accessed using this hostname (URLs have to be like `https://[hostname]:...` for certificate check to pass).

If your network doesn't have a DNS already, you might use something like [MaraDNS](https://maradns.samiam.org/) hosted on your dev-machine (see P.S. for sample configuration).

### Generate certificate (and signing key) in various formats

self_signed_template.config:

```
[req]
default_bits       = 2048
default_md         = sha256
prompt             = no
default_keyfile    = [hostname]_self_signed_key.pem
encrypt_key        = no

distinguished_name = dn

req_extensions     = v3_req
x509_extensions    = v3_req

[dn]
C            = PF
ST           = Tahiti
L            = Papeete
O            = c4-soft
emailAddress = ch4mp@c4-soft.com
CN           = [hostname]

[v3_req]
subjectAltName   = critical, @alt_names
basicConstraints = critical, CA:false
keyUsage         = critical, keyCertSign, nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = critical, serverAuth, clientAuth

[alt_names]
DNS.1 = [hostname]
DNS.2 = localhost
DNS.3 = 10.0.2.2
```

self_signed.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
  echo "Usage:"
  echo ""
  echo "self_signed.sh key_password [java_home] [hostname] [store_password] [certificates_directory_path] [cacerts_password]"
  echo ""
  echo "  - java_home is defaulted to $JAVA_HOME"
  echo "  - hostname is defaulted to $HOSTNAME"
  echo "  - store_password is defaulted to key_password"
  echo "  - certificates_directory_path is defaulted to current diretory"
  echo "  - cacerts_password is defaulted to changeit"
  echo ""
  echo "Sample:"
  echo "./self_signed.sh \"secr3!\" \"C:/Java/jdk1.8.0_281\" \"bravo-ch4mp\""
  echo ""
  exit 1
else

  echo "#------------------------------------------"
  echo "# This is a no-op script"
  echo "# Copy / paste output to:"
  echo "#   - generate certificate files"
  echo "#   - import certificates into cacerts file"
  echo "#------------------------------------------"
  
  KEY_PASSWORD="${1}"
  echo "# key password: $KEY_PASSWORD"
  
  if [ -z "$2" ]
  then
    if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]
    then
      echo "ERROR: could not locate java home"
      exit 1
    else
      JAVA=$JAVA_HOME
    fi
  else
    JAVA=$2
  fi
  JAVA=$(echo $JAVA | sed 's/\\/\//g')
  echo "# java home: $JAVA"
  
  if [ -f "${JAVA}/lib/security/cacerts" ]
  then
    # recent JDKs and JREs style
    CACERTS="${JAVA}/lib/security/cacerts"
  elif [ -f "${JAVA}/jre/lib/security/cacerts" ]
  then
    # legacy JDKs style (1.8 and older)
    CACERTS="${JAVA}/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
  else
    echo "ERROR: could not locate cacerts under ${JAVA}"
    exit 1
  fi
  echo "# cacerts path: $CACERTS"
  
  if [ -z "${3}" ]
  then
    HOST="$HOSTNAME"
  else
    HOST="${3}"
  fi
  echo "# host (certificate CN): $HOST"
  
  if [ -z "${4}" ]
  then
    STORE_PASSWORD="$KEY_PASSWORD"
  else
    STORE_PASSWORD="${4}"
  fi
  echo "# store password : $STORE_PASSWORD"
  
  if [ -z "${5}" ]
  then
    CERTIF_DIR="."
  else
    CERTIF_DIR="${5}"
  fi
  echo "# certificates directory path: $CERTIF_DIR"
  CERTIF_DIR=$(echo $CERTIF_DIR | sed 's/\\/\//g')
  
  if [ -z "${6}" ]
  then
    CACERTS_PASSWORD="changeit"
  else
    CACERTS_PASSWORD="${6}"
  fi
  echo "# cacerts password: $CACERTS_PASSWORD" 
  echo "#------------------------------------------"
fi

echo ""

rm -f ${HOST}_self_signed.config;
sed 's/\[hostname\]/'${HOST}'/g' "${CERTIF_DIR}/self_signed_template.config" > "${CERTIF_DIR}/${HOST}_self_signed.config"

echo openssl req -config \"${CERTIF_DIR}/${HOST}_self_signed.config\" -new -keyout \"${CERTIF_DIR}/${HOST}_self_signed_key.pem\" -out \"${CERTIF_DIR}/${HOST}_self_signed_cert.pem\" -reqexts v3_req
echo ""

echo openssl x509 -req -days 365 -extfile \"${CERTIF_DIR}/${HOST}_self_signed.config\" -in \"${CERTIF_DIR}/${HOST}_self_signed_cert.pem\" -extensions v3_req -signkey \"${CERTIF_DIR}/${HOST}_self_signed_key.pem\" -out \"${CERTIF_DIR}/${HOST}_self_signed.crt\"
echo ""

echo openssl pkcs12 -export -in \"${CERTIF_DIR}/${HOST}_self_signed.crt\" -inkey \"${CERTIF_DIR}/${HOST}_self_signed_key.pem\" -name ${HOST}_self_signed -password pass:${KEY_PASSWORD} -out \"${CERTIF_DIR}/${HOST}_self_signed.pfx\"
echo ""

echo \"${JAVA}/bin/keytool\" -importkeystore -srckeystore \"${CERTIF_DIR}/${HOST}_self_signed.pfx\" -srcstorepass \"${STORE_PASSWORD}\" -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcalias ${HOST}_self_signed -destkeystore \"${CERTIF_DIR}/${HOST}_self_signed.jks\" -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass ${STORE_PASSWORD} -destalias ${HOST}_self_signed
echo ""

echo \"${JAVA}/bin/keytool\" -importkeystore -srckeystore \"${CERTIF_DIR}/${HOST}_self_signed.pfx\" -srcstorepass \"${STORE_PASSWORD}\" -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcalias ${HOST}_self_signed -destkeystore \"${CACERTS}\" -deststorepass ${CACERTS_PASSWORD} -destalias ${HOST}_self_signed
echo ""
```

Then run something like `./self_signed.sh "secr3!" C:/Java/jdk1.8.0_281`.

Execute `./self_signed.sh` for each of your JDKs / JREs and then
Simply copy / paste / run all output commands at 1st execution and **last command only** (import certificate in JDK / JRE `cacerts` file) from 2nd execution on (otherwise you'll loose previous certificates).

Admin privileges could be required to import the certificate in Java's cacerts.

On windows, Git Bash  has all of `sed`, `openssl` and `keytool` on the path.

### Import this certificate as trusted root authority

If you add this certificate to trusted root authorities, your browser will display no error nor warning when navigating URLs like `https://[hostname]:...`.

On windows, this can be done with `certmgr.msc` (right click trusted root authorities and then import). Please comment if you successfully do the same on other OS.

### Configure Ionic-Angular to serve over https with this certificate

Edit `angular.json` to set "sslCert" and "sslKey" under `your-project/architect/serve/options/` and point it to respectively `[hostname]_self_signed.crt` and `[hostname]_self_signed_key.pem` generated earlier.

This is enough for the right certificate to be picked when running `ionic serve --ssl --host=[hostname]` or `ionic capacitor run android -l --ssl --host=[hostname]`

### Embed certificate in Android project

Reminder: android resource folder is `android/app/src/main/res/` under your project or `app/res/` in Android Studio

First, copy `[hostname]_self_signed.crt` to `raw` resources, replacing `-`, if any, with `_` in hostname.

Create `network_security_config.xml` in xml resources (careful with modified hostname)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
          <certificates src="@raw/[hostname]_self_signed"/>
          <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

important note: if all your trafic is served over https, you should set `cleartextTrafficPermitted` to false (which is default value since Android 9). Consider doing so for prod build at least.

Finally, edit `AndroidManifest.xml` and add `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` to your `<application >` tag

### Embed certificate in iOS project

I have no experience with iOS, please feel free to comment or add an answer if you get it working.

### Configure your backends to serve over https with self-signed certificate

Well... it really depends on the stack you use. A few samples:

- For Kestrel (.Net app debugged in Visual Studio), set `ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password` and `ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path`, the second pointing to the `[hostname]_self_signed.pfx`
- For spring-boot, copy `[hostname]_self_signed.jks` into `src/main/resources/` and set [`server.ssl`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-ssl) properties
- Keycloak has comprensive doc to [setup the server](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/) with custom certificate
- Please comment if you get other backend types working

**P.S.** The `dwood3rc.txt` file I use for MaraDNS:

```
#upstream_servers = {}
#upstream_servers["."]="8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4" # Servers we connect to 
root_servers = {}
# ICANN DNS root servers 
root_servers["."]="198.41.0.4, 199.9.14.201, 192.33.4.12, 199.7.91.13,"
root_servers["."]+="192.203.230.10, 192.5.5.241, 192.112.36.4, "
root_servers["."]+="198.97.190.53, 192.36.148.17, 192.58.128.30, "
root_servers["."]+="193.0.14.129, 199.7.83.42, 202.12.27.33"
# local DNS server
root_servers["bravo-ch4mp."]="192.168.1.181"
root_servers["local."]="192.168.1.181"

# The IP this program has 
bind_address="127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.181, 192.168.1.132"

# The IPs allowed to connect and use the cache
recursive_acl = "127.0.0.1/16, 192.168.0.1/16"

chroot_dir = "/etc/maradns"

# This is the file Deadwood uses to read the cache to and from disk
cache_file = "dw_cache_bin"

filter_rfc1918 = 0

ip4 = {}
ip4["bravo-ch4mp."] = "192.168.1.181"

ip6 = {}
```

Once the DNS server is up (`net start deadwood`) on my dev machine (and also firewall configured...), I configure clients to use it as primary DNS (edit wifi network properties which does not require rooted device) et voilà!

**P.S.2** Keycloak standalone configuration allowing test devices to connect to OpenId endpoints over https

Copy `[hostname]_self_signed.jks` to `standalone/configuration/`.

Edit `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` to replace `${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}` with `${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}`. Save and close.

Start Keycloak with `bin/standalone[.bat|.sh]`, then using `bin/jboss-cli[.bat|.sh]`:

```
connect
/subsystem=keycloak-server/spi=hostname/provider=default:write-attribute(name=properties.frontendUrl,value="https://[hostname]:8443/auth")
/core-service=management/security-realm=UndertowRealm:add()
/core-service=management/security-realm=UndertowRealm/server-identity=ssl:add(keystore-path=[hostname]_self_signed.jks, keystore-relative-to=jboss.server.config.dir, keystore-password=[keystore_password])
/subsystem=undertow/server=default-server/https-listener=https:write-attribute(name=security-realm, value=UndertowRealm)
reload
```